# onClick event in VB.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, onclick

I am programming in VB.NET.
I am trying to make an onClick event for a div tag. How can I make this in the code behind?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible solution would be to create a Webusercontrol with a Panel(will be rendered as DIV) and an invisible Button(Display:none). Onclick of the div you could click the button per javascript which would cause an automatic Postback. In Codebehind you would catch that ButtonClick-Event and Raise a custom event(DivClicked). So you can reuse that control everywhere. Something like this:

**ClickableDiv.ascx**

```
<%@ Control Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="ClickableDiv.ascx.vb" Inherits="WebApplication1.ClickableDiv" %>
<asp:Panel id="TheDiv" runat="server" onMouseOver="this.style.cursor='pointer'"  onclick="this.nextSibling.click()" /><asp:Button ID="DivButton" runat="server"  />
```

**ClickableDiv.ascx Codebehind**

```
Partial Public Class ClickableDiv
    Inherits System.Web.UI.UserControl

    Public Event DivClicked(ByVal src As ClickableDiv)

    Private Sub Page_Init(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Init
        Me.DivButton.Style.Add("display", "none")
    End Sub

    Public ReadOnly Property Div() As Panel
        Get
            Return Me.TheDiv
        End Get
    End Property

    Protected Sub DivButton_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles DivButton.Click
        RaiseEvent DivClicked(Me)
    End Sub

End Class
```

And for example in any page(drag&drop it to the designer):

```
    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Dim imgTest As New Image
        imgTest.ImageUrl = "http://skins.gmodules.com/ig/images/logos/approved/white.png"
        Me.ClickableDiv1.Div.Controls.Add(imgTest)
    End Sub

    Private Sub ClickableDiv1_DivClicked(ByVal src As ClickableDiv) Handles ClickableDiv1.DivClicked
        Dim div As ClickableDiv = src
    End Sub
```

Btw, you could also use the [__doPostback-function](http://www.codedigest.com/Articles/ASPNET/320_Doing_or_Raising_Postback_using___doPostBack%28%29_function_from_Javascript_in_AspNet.aspx) on the DIV's onclick event to raise a Postback.

Comment: Yep, that's how i'd do it too. +1

Answer (score 0):

1- create hidden asp:button

2- on div click `document.getElementById('<%=HiddenButton.ClientID%>').click();` this will fire button_click event on server

** remember to set `UseSubmitBehaviour=false` for the hidden button to make click event works